# stdout and stderr is not visible in syslog

Tags: linux, logging

We have a node.js application running as a daemon on a Linux (Yocto) gateway, but I see no trace from the application in the /var/log/syslog file. What would I have to do to include all console.log (stdout) messages into the syslog file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is not a development question and would be better on Superuser or other site.

But anyway.

You can pipe the output of the program through a program called `logger` which will copy all of its input into the log socket.

Or you could use a version of Linux that uses systemd and journald. The systemd log system will copy all stdout and stderr into its journal log.

Or you can use your own log file (not /var/log/syslog) and redirect the daemon's output into that file.

Comment: All console.log output gets visible in journalctl, but is never persisted in syslog. So the question is if there is a configuration in the .service file of /etc/syslog.conf that I could or need to do...

Comment: @wmmhihaa Using rsyslogd? You have to either forward journald to rsyslog or have rsyslog import from journald. Only pick one.